# Flattening list

Tags: python

I'm taking a Python class on EDx and am stuck on this assignment. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction on here.

The instructions are here:

> 8.4 Open the file romeo.txt and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The
> program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check
> to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the
> list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words
> in alphabetical order. You can download the sample data at

This is the data I am to parse:

> But soft what light through yonder window breaks
> It is the east and Juliet is the sun
> Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
> Who is already sick and pale with grief

Below is my code:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ") 
fh = open(fname)  
lst = []  
for lines in fh:
    word = lines.split()
    lst.append(word) 
    print(last)
```

Which creates a list of all the sentences. So then I try:

```
lst = [] 
for lines in fh:
    for words in lines:
        word = words.split()
        lst.append(word) 
        print(last)
```

and I get the following:

> [['B'], ['u'], ['t'], [], ['s'], ['o'], ['f'], ['t'], [], ['w'],
> ['h'], ['a'], ['t'], [], ['l'], ['i'], ['g'], ['h'], ['t'], [], ['t'],
> ['h'], ['r'], ['o'], ['u'], ['g'], ['h'], [], ['y'], ['o'], ['n'],
> ['d'], ['e'], ['r'], [], ['w'], ['i'], ['n'], ['d'], ['o'], ['w'], [],
> ['b'], ['r'], ['e'], ['a'], ['k'], ['s'], [], ['I'], ['t'], [], ['i'],
> ['s'], [], ['t'], ['h'], ['e'], [], ['e'], ['a'], ['s'], ['t'], [],
> ['a'], ['n'], ['d'], [], ['J'], ['u'], ['l'], ['i'], ['e'], ['t'], [],
> ['i'], ['s'], [], ['t'], ['h'], ['e'], [], ['s'], ['u'], ['n'], [],
> ['A'], ['r'], ['i'], ['s'], ['e'], [], ['f'], ['a'], ['i'], ['r'], [],
> ['s'], ['u'], ['n'], [], ['a'], ['n'], ['d'], [], ['k'], ['i'], ['l'],
> ['l'], [], ['t'], ['h'], ['e'], [], ['e'], ['n'], ['v'], ['i'], ['o'],
> ['u'], ['s'], [], ['m'], ['o'], ['o'], ['n'], [], ['W'], ['h'], ['o'],
> [], ['i'], ['s'], [], ['a'], ['l'], ['r'], ['e'], ['a'], ['d'], ['y'],
> [], ['s'], ['i'], ['c'], ['k'], [], ['a'], ['n'], ['d'], [], ['p'],
> ['a'], ['l'], ['e'], [], ['w'], ['i'], ['t'], ['h'], [], ['g'], ['r'],
> ['i'], ['e'], ['f'], []]

how to approach this?

Comment: `for words in lines` just because you use the variable name `word` doesn't make you magically iterate over words. `lines` is a string. Iterating over a string iterates over the individual characters of that string.

Comment: So, using your original approach, instead of *appending* to the list, use extend, so `lst.extend(word)`, which is equivalent to doing `for w in word: lst.append(w)`, i.e., iterating over the list of words and appending each word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Used the same code as you wrote, so that you find it easier to understand.*

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ") 
fh = open(fname)  
lst = []  

for lines in fh:
    words = lines.split()
    
    for word in words:
        # check to see if the word already exists in the list, only append if not
        if not word in lst:
            lst.append(word) 

#sorting the list in alphabetical order 
lst.sort()

print(lst)

# Output: ['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east', 'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick', 'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code below

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
try:
    fh = open(fname)
except:
    print("Invalid input!")
    exit()

lst = list()
for line in fh:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in lst: lst.append(word)

lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for lines in fh:
    # "lines" is one input line on each iteration, as you expect.
    # Each line is a single string, ending with a newline.

    for words in lines:
         # "words" is one character at a time, 
         # that being what you get when you iterate through a string.
```

If you want individual words, then you have to `split` the input line, such as

```
    for words in lines.split():
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split word by `' '`.

Use `words = line.split(' ')`

Instead of `word = words.split()`

Now you can access every word using for loop.

Following code opens the file and read it line by line, then it splits every word of the line by space `' '` and appends it to words list.

```
path = input('Enter file name: ')

words = []
with open(path) as _file:
    for line in _file:
        words.extend(line.split(' '))
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've solved it with the following

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ") 
fh = open(fname)

lst = [] 
fltlst =[]

for lines in fh:
    line = lines.split()
    for words in line:
        word = words.split()
        if not word in lst:
            lst.append(word)

for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        fltlst.append(j)


fltlst.sort()

print(fltlst)
```